# Aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

> Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 191
> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Code:

```
select  
    count(i.item_id), warehouse_id 
from 
    items_in_warehouse i
where 
    date_from >= '2021-01-01' 
    and date_from <= '2021-03-31' 
    and count(warehouse_id) >= 5 
    and count(warehouse_id) <= 10 
group by 
    warehouse_id;
```

I think the problem is with the count function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means that aggregate functions (count) can only be used for filtering in a having clause

```
select count(i.item_id), warehouse_id from items_in_warehouse i
where date_from >= '2021-01-01' and date_from <= '2021-03-31'
group by warehouse_id
having count(warehouse_id) >= 5 and count(warehouse_id) <= 10;
```

unless it is in a subquery in a having clause

```
select count(i.item_id), warehouse_id from items_in_warehouse i
where date_from >= '2021-01-01' and date_from <= '2021-03-31'
group by warehouse_id
having (select count(1) from limits where limits.lower < count(i.item_id)) > 5
```

something like that

Answer (score 2):

The error message is almost telling you how to fix it, you need to use `having` to filter on an aggregate:

You would filter using `having` after the `group by`

```
having count(warehouse_id) between 5 and 10;
```